# AngularJS: How to properly set/unset a variable with a directive repeated using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a directive that essentially should set a variable of the global scope to a certain value, if the mouse is clicked on it and return to the default value, once the mouse is released.

I got it to work but as I am just starting with angular I really try to do things proper and avoid even starting with bad programming habits.

There's also some DOM manipulation happening in the directive but I simplified it to the basic functionality of changing the value.

This is the HTML:

```
<th ng-repeat="item in list" my-directive="{{$index}}" ng-model="clicked.current"></th>
```

And this is the (simplified) directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        model: "=ngModel",
        index: "@myDirective"
      },
      template: "<button ng-mousedown='mousedown()'>click</button>",
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        scope.mousedown = function () {
          scope.model = scope.index;
          angular.element(document).one("mouseup", function () { // react even if dragged out of element bounds
            scope.$apply(function () {
              scope.model = -1;
            });
          });
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

It is working as expected but I am unsure if it is the best and most correct way of achieving this.

My Questions are:

1. For this purpose - did I chose the correct approach?
2. Is it okay, that I defined the mousedown method in the link function or should I define a seperate controler for the directive using the "controller" option?
3. Is there a way to achieve the same thing (i.e. with just one parameter to the directive)? (I read one should avoid using scope.$parent.$index).
4. General comments / advice?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's really hard to tell if you're doing things correctly because it's very blurry what problem you're trying to solve. Anyways, using events binding is perfectly fine within a directive, no problem with that.

Comment: Also, working with ngModel is recommended using ngModelController (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: I am unsure how to put it more clear than in my first sentence. Click element -> x=index of current element, release mouse -> x=-1.
As I said the directive works, I am just wondering if I am doing this correctly in a formal sense.
I'll look into ngModelController...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish the same thing easier without ngModel. 
You can work directly with parent scope variables within a directive. Just remove this bit:

```
  scope: {
    model: "=ngModel",
    index: "@myDirective"
  },
```

This means the scope is isolated. You could remove this and simply read the index from `attrs` argument in link function. 
Keep some state in the controllers `$scope`:

```
$scope.data = {};
```

and then in a directive you can read/write stuff to controller's scope like so (assuming your directive's scope is no longer isolated):

`$scope.data.someVar = 1`

Note: It's important to keep variables you want to read/write from child scopes in an object. I recommend reading this to better understand scope inheritance:

[Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: Mh I don't think this best practice. Especially if I may want to reuse the component an isolated scope should be the way to go, right?

Comment: I guess you're right. If you're planning to reuse the component it's a bad idea to couple it with parent scope. `ngModelController` is the way to go then.